# Oracle Apex Refresh Shuttle Item after Close Modal Window

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex, I have a parent page and trough that page I open a Modal window for inserting some data to database. after close the modal I need to refresh shuttle item (without submit) on my parent page, I expect in the "shuttle available list" I see the new inserted record which I inseret through modal window and in "shuttle selected list", I see the record I have saved before in related table to my parent page. but unfortunately the behavior of shuttle item is completely different with an other type of Apex items. I don't have any problem to refresh any type of item except SHUTTLE. my version of oracle apex is 20.2
I will be so thankful if you have any useful, clear and tested solution.